# Create a downloadable URL for image byte array

Tags: java, base64

I have a Java application which receives images as Base64 string. I can convert it to byteArray as below:

```
byte[] imageBytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64ImageString)
```

How do I save this as a downloadable URL to show that URL on my front end application for user to download and view?

Comment: Use a FileOutputStream to write the bytes to disk. Place the file whereever your web server expects static images to serve.

Comment: What is a “front end application,” exactly?  Web application?  Swing?  JavaFX?  Do you want the user to be able to download the image from a web page?  From a button in a desktop application?

Comment: The front end is a web application. So save them on the webserver static content folder and load them through a hyperlink to that location?